# ASP.Net MVC Application Root and Routing

Tags: c#, iis, model-view-controller, routes

I have a requirement in an MVC app to set the app root to lowercase in all URLs without setting the ID and querystring to lowercase and not quite sure how to go about it.  I can't change the directories to lowercase and I have limited access to IIS so I'm hoping I can find a programmatic way to do this within the application.

For instance if I have several versions of an app called MYAPP with 3 versions (V1, V2, V3) which each are in their own directories giving us /MYAPP/V1, /MYAPP/V2, and /MYAPP/V3.

When MVC constructs the URL it will use the application root that is in uppercase, but I want to set it to lowercase, where

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Products", new { id = "ABC", Module = "CS" }, null)
```

would result in

```
<a href="/myapp/v1/Products/Edit/ABC?Module=CS">Edit</a>
```

and not

```
<a href="/MYAPP/V1/Products/Edit/ABC?Module=CS">Edit</a>
```

I have looked at using

```
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
```

In the RouteConfig.cs but wouldn't that end up giving me

```
<a href="/myapp/v1/products/edit/abc?module=cs">Edit</a>
```

Which is not what I want... any advise is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The route part is Products/Edit/ABC?Module=CS.

1. A quick solution would be to add a global HTTP module which checks the /MYAPP/V1 part of the url and redirect user to /myapp/v1. (a simple comparision of if current url starts with http://yourdomain/MYAPP/V1, make it case sensitive)
2. You can also write your own extension to override the behaviour of ActionLink method.

Source code of ActionLink method - 
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/749384689e027a2fcd29eb79a9137b94cea611a8/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LinkExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using url rewrite to help you acheive this requirement.

The url rewrite has build-in ToLower function which could help you make your url to lower.

You could install it from this [url]{https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite}.

Then you could add below config setting into your web.config:

```
            <rule name="TolowerCase" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
              <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="([A-Z]+)" ignoreCase="false" />

              </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://{ToLower:{HTTP_HOST}{PATH_INFO}}?{ToLower:{QUERY_STRING}}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Result:

[image]